# Div already filling its spot before it transitions in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am dynamically rendering and animating a div. It works just fine, but it kind of "pops" the other div out of place and doesn't smoothly push it down or pull it back up.

So essentially I have a button with two divs underneath it. The first div is not rendered until you click the button. The second div then shoves down instantly and clears the space for the div. When you hit the button again it waits for the other div to render off the screen and pops back up abruptly.

The problem is I can't just pull up the second div because when the first div isn't rendered it would just cover up my button, and I can't just animate it down when the second div comes in or else it would be to low. So I am kind of stuck here.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      show: false,
      shouldRender: false,
      class: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (!prevState.show && this.state.show) {
      this.setState({
        shouldRender: true
      })
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ class: 'showDiv' })
      }, 0)
    }
    if (prevState.show && !this.state.show) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          shouldRender: false
        })
      }, 1000)
      this.setState({ class: '' })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      
        <button
          style={{
            display: 'block',
            border: 'none',
            padding: '20px',
            background: 'blue',
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: '20px',
            margin: '10px',
            cursor: 'pointer'
          }}
          onClick={() => this.setState({ show: !this.state.show }) }
        >
          Toggle Div
        </button>

        {this.state.shouldRender && <div className={`baseDiv ${this.state.class}`} />}

        <div
          style={{
            width: '200px',
            height: '200px',
            background: '#999',
            margin: '5px'
          }}
        />
        
      </div>
     )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.baseDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transform: translateY(-200%);
}
.showDiv {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also animate the second div at the same time. I used the same `showDiv` class to trigger the animation on the secondDiv as well. Another big problem is that as soon as the first div get's rendered, it's whole height gets accounted for (200px) which **instantly** pushes the secondDiv down. Instead, give your firstDiv a `position: absolute` so that it's height doesn't affect the secondDiv when it is added to the dom:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      show: false,
      shouldRender: false,
      class: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (!prevState.show && this.state.show) {
      this.setState({
        shouldRender: true
      })
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ class: 'showDiv' })
      }, 0)
    }
    if (prevState.show && !this.state.show) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          shouldRender: false
        })
      }, 1000)
      this.setState({ class: '' })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
      
        <button
          style={{
            display: 'block',
            border: 'none',
            padding: '20px',
            background: 'blue',
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: '20px',
            margin: '10px',
            cursor: 'pointer'
          }}
          onClick={() => this.setState({ show: !this.state.show }) }
        >
          Toggle Div
        </button>

        {this.state.shouldRender && <div className={`baseDiv ${this.state.class}`} />}

        <div
          className={`secondDiv ${this.state.class}`}
          style={{
            width: '200px',
            height: '200px',
            background: '#999',
            margin: '5px'
          }}
        />
        
      </div>
     )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.baseDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transform: translateY(-200%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 0;
}
.showDiv {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.secondDiv {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
.secondDiv.showDiv {
  transform: translateY(105%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Didn't think about the position absolute to eliminate the height problem, I am new to all this animation , and relatively new to this type of css as well, thank you!